# Dealing with nullable UUID in a controller - SpringBoot and Postgres

Tags: spring-boot, uuid

I have an entity that includes a nullable UUID (but it is not an ID), as follows:

```
  @Column(nullable = true)
  var myField: UUID? = null
```

I also have a dto converter as follows:

```
myField = entity.myField.let { it }
```

I can correctly store a null value for the UUID field, but when inspecting the GET response from my controller whenever I pass a null value for such field the body does not contain the `myField` at all. What is the reason for that? How does SpringBoot deal with null value for UUID.

Thanks

Comment: Print the object in the controller class and verify if it is null, if it is null but the response body does not include it, please adjust the Jackson ObjectMapper to include null value.